# How can I create a GenericCredential in WebLogic OPSS CSF through WLST?

Tags: weblogic

WebLogic's OPSS security runtime Credential Store Framework (CSF) supports [two kinds of credential](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/idm/app-security/csfadmin.htm#JISEC2948): a standard username+password *password* type, and a single token or *generic* type.

There's a few APIs that can be accessed to read and write CSF maps - Java POJOs, and there's [WLST access to createCred](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/idm/wlst-reference/custom_infra_security.htm#IDMCR1438).  That however will create password-style key/values, not generic entries if one is desired.  You can create a generic entry through the Enterprise Manager `/em`.

Is there a way to create a generic style credential entry through WLST scripting?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you need to use lower-level APIs within WLST than the provided `createCred` - specifically you need to access configuration via JMX MBean e.g. [JpsCredentialMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/idm/mbeans-api-ref/oracle/security/jps/mas/mgmt/jmx/credstore/JpsCredentialMXBean.html).

Here's a sample WLST script which contains one credential of each type in a map:

```
import os;
import sys;
import time;

admin_serverHostName = sys.argv[1]
admin_port = sys.argv[2]
admin_protocol = sys.argv[3]

connect(os.environ["WLS_USERNAME"], os.environ["WLS_PASSWORD"], admin_protocol+'://'+admin_serverHostName+':'+admin_port)

domainRuntime()
jpsCredentialStore = ObjectName("com.oracle.jps:type=JpsCredentialStore")

# create normal password credential
pc = createCredObj("username", "password", "description")
cd = pc.toCompositeData(None)
params = ["map.key", "key.name", cd]
sign = ["java.lang.String", "java.lang.String", "javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData"]
mbs.invoke(jpsCredentialStore, "setPortableCredential", params, sign)

# generic style single-token credential
params = ["map.key", "key.name", "token", "description"]
sign = ["java.lang.String", "java.lang.String", "java.io.Serializable", "java.lang.String"]
mbs.invoke(jpsCredentialStore, "reassignGenericCredential", params, sign)

disconnect()

def createCredObj(user, password, desc) :
    from oracle.security.jps.mas.mgmt.jmx.credstore import PortablePasswordCredential
    #Create Password Credential object
    pc = PortablePasswordCredential(user, password, desc)
    return pc
```